# Chamar uma action do controller para as views

Tags: controller, view, yii, yii2

Estou utilizando o Yii2 e fazendo um projeto de site em que uma das funcionalidades é listar os filmes vinculados a um usuário específico. Eu já possuo um método para associar os filmes as contas e um que faz o inner join das tabelas.

(Código das actions):

```
public function actionAssociarFilme($idFilme){
    $model = new FilmeHasCompra();
    $model->Filme_idFilme = $idFilme;
    $model->Usuario_idUsuario = Yii::$app->user->identity->idUsuario;
    $model->save();
    return $this->goBack();
}
public function actionListarFilme(){
    $resultado = Filme::find()
    ->innerJoin('filme_has_compra', 'filme_has_compra.Filme_idFilme=Filme.idFilme')
    ->where('filme_has_compra.Usuario_idUsuario=:idusuario',['idusuario'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->idUsuario]) ->all();

    return $this->render('tables',['resultado'=>$resultado]);


}
```

}

A dúvida é como chamar essa action ListarFilme na visão, pois quando eu tento chamar ele aparece um erro de unknown method[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ao invés de utilizar imagem do código, copie e cole. Assim será mais fácil para alguém responder a pergunta.

Comment: Sua duvida é como chamar a action pois tá ocorrendo o erro "unknown method", mas você não deixou claro onde esta chamando esta ação. Podeiria colocar o trecho com a linha que ocorre esse erro? Será mais fácil assim achar uma solução.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente importe o controlador responsável pela action.

E tente algo do tipo:

```
Yii::$app->runAction('controller/action', ['primeiroParametro' => 'primeiroValor', 'segundoParametro' => 'segundoValor']);
```

Porém eu te aconselho a não quebrar o esquema do MVC, com isso você poderia usar uma **Widget** ou uma **ViewHelper**.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?=Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('listarFilme', ['param1'=>1111, ''=> 22222]) ?>
```

No entanto precisas alterar o "render" da ActionLstarFilme "renderPartial" também caso contrario vais incluir a “layot” duas vezes

```
return $this->renderPartial('tables',['resultado'=>$resultado]);
```